# CATIA Macro add bodies into new body

Tags: vba, excel, catia

I would like to program a macro that will select:

- All Bodies named "name_1" and add them to new body with name "new group 1"
- All Bodies named "name_2" and add them to new body with name "new group 2"
- All Bodies named "name_3" and add them to new body with name "new group 3"

I successfully wrote this code on my CATIA R20, and works OK. It adds all bodies in new body. 
But then i tried to run a macro on CATIA R19 and R24, but it doesnt work! In R19/R24 it doesn't add all bodies named "name_1" but it adds only one body in new body!

```
Sub CATMain()
    Dim partDocument1 As PartDocument    
    Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument    
    Set objSel = partDocument1.Selection

    Dim part1 As Part    
    Set part1 = partDocument1.Part
    Dim bodies1 As Bodies    
    Set bodies1 = part1.Bodies

    Set shapeFactory1 = part1.ShapeFactory    
    Set bodies1 = part1.Bodies    
    Dim body1 As Body    
    Set body1 = bodies1.Item("PartBody")    
    Dim shapes1 As Shapes    
    Set shapes1 = body1.Shapes    
    objSel.Clear

    '******************name_1*********************    
    objSel.Search ("Name=name_1,all")    
    objcount = objSel.Count    

    Set body1 = bodies1.Add()    
    body1.Name = "new_name_1"

    Set body1 = bodies1.Item("new_name_1")
    part1.InWorkObject = body1

    For i = 1 To objcount
    Set body11 = bodies1.Item("name_1")
    Set add1 = shapeFactory1.AddNewAdd(body11)
    Next
    objSel.Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Catia, if you have multiple features with the same name, Catia only recognizes the first feature. So when you:

```
Set body11 = bodies1.Item("name_1")
```

You previously did a search for all the bodies named "name_1", if there are multiple it will only take the first one.

So I would do something like:

```
Sub CATMain()
Dim partDocument1 As PartDocument    
Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument    
Set objSel = partDocument1.Selection

Dim part1 As Part    
Set part1 = partDocument1.Part
Dim bodies1 As Bodies    
Set bodies1 = part1.Bodies

Dim cBodies as new collection

Set shapeFactory1 = part1.ShapeFactory    
Set bodies1 = part1.Bodies    
Dim body1 As Body    
Set body1 = bodies1.Item("PartBody")    
Dim shapes1 As Shapes    
Set shapes1 = body1.Shapes    
objSel.Clear

'******************name_1*********************    
objSel.Search ("Name=name_1,all")    
objcount = objSel.Count    

'Check if search found something
If objcount > 0 then
    'add selected objects to a collection
     For i = 1 To objcount
        cBodies.Add objSel.Item(i).value
     next
     objSel.clear

     Set body1 = bodies1.Add()    
     body1.Name = "new_name_1"

    'Set body1 = bodies1.Item("new_name_1") 'You dont need to do this because you set it 3 lines up
    'part1.InWorkObject = body1 'Not needed, Any new feature will automatically be the inworkobject

For i = 1 To objcount
    Set add1 = shapeFactory1.AddNewAdd(cBodies1.Item(i))
Next

part1.UpdateObject body1 'Update the body

End if

End Sub
```