CATIA V5 boolean operation in C#
I'm new in Catia c#. I didn't find a source or solution for boolean operations in Catia.
I wanted to create some bodies after that using boolean operations on those bodies.
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PartDocument partDoc = (PartDocument)myCATIA.ActiveDocument;
    Part part = partDoc.Part;

    Body body1 = part.Bodies.Add();
    Body body2 = part.Bodies.Add();
    Body body3 = part.Bodies.Add();

    body1.set_Name("A");
    body2.set_Name("B");
    body3.set_Name("C");

    ShapeFactory shapeFactory = (ShapeFactory)part.ShapeFactory;
    Body addNewAdd = shapeFactory.AddNewAdd(body1 ,body2);
}

In this part addnewadd blows up.
ShapeFactory shapeFactory = (ShapeFactory)part.ShapeFactory;
Body addNewAdd = shapeFactory.*AddNewAdd*(body1 ,body2);

In this last part of the code it creates what I needed but I got errors in addNewRemove...
System.InvalidCastException: ''System.__ComObject' türündeki COM nesnesi 'PARTITF.Add' arabirim türüne atanamadı. '{80EBCA5F-B839-0000-0280-030BA6000000}' IID'sine sahip arabirim için COM bileşenindeki QueryInterface çağrısı aşağıdaki hatayla başarısız olduğundan bu işlem başarısız oldu: Böyle bir arabirim desteklenmiyor (HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'
ShapeFactory shapeFactory = (ShapeFactory)part.ShapeFactory;
ShapeFactory shapeFactory2 = (ShapeFactory)part.ShapeFactory; 

Add addNewAdd = shapeFactory.AddNewAdd(body2); 
Add addNewRemove = (Add)shapeFactory2.AddNewRemove(body1);

With a button I can create bodies and names but I didn't figure it out how to use add remove in the code.
So basically I just wanted like this in my tree:
TREE

Please have a look onto the methods (e.g. AddNewAdd, AddNewAssemble) of the ShapeFactory

@Shrotter Hello friend how can I find this commands like this sorry for asking. Is there any source for those? And thank you

please check the api documentation: V5automation.chm in the catia installation folders

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28031396/catia-macro-add-bodies-into-new-body

It's vba @Disvoys

@Shrotter  I tried but failed can you give me a good example pls...  it says Add ShapeFactory.AddNewAdd(Body iBodyToAdd)    But no idea.

I know its VBA...see and read my sample. Addnewadd does not return a body. Then why are you using 2 arguments when thé fonction only need one ? Please read the sample i gave. Use InWorkObjext on your main body, and use shapefactory.addnewadd(2ndBody)

Add addNewAdd = shapeFactory.AddNewAdd(body2)

Thank you friends I solved it with yours help.

I figure It out how to make it.
ShapeFactory shapeFactory = (ShapeFactory)part.ShapeFactory;
part.InWorkObject = body3;

Add addNewAdd = shapeFactory.AddNewAdd(body2);
Add addNewAdd2 = shapeFactory.AddNewAdd(body4);
Remove addNewRemove = shapeFactory.AddNewRemove(body1);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
